# Powershell IF statements - How to pass "-match" or "-like"

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am working on an automation for installing software. The step I am currently working on is either executing a .msi file, or unzipping and moving a directory to the appropriate location for deployment. I am trying to utilize an IF statement to accomplish this, however, if my IF or ElseIF arguments are true, it still appears to pass through to the "Else" statement. My example is as follows:

```
$pattern2 = "abc"
$pattern3 = "Dot NET ABC"
$pattern4 = "ABC Serial Example"
$path2 = "C:Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\" 
$ABSystem1 = Get-ChildItem -path $path2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match $pattern2}
$ABSystem2 = Get-ChildItem -path $path2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match $pattern3}
$ABSystem3 = Get-ChildItem -path $path2 | Where-Object {$_.Name -Match $pattern4}
$Destination2 = "C:Test\test-systems\$ClientName\ab\$ClientName\"
$InstallAB = {if ($ABSyetem1 -Match $pattern2 ) {
    $ABName1 = $ABsystem1.Name
    Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\Users\$env:UserName\Downloads\$AbName1" -DestinationPath $Destination2
}
elseif ($ABSyetem2 -Match $pattern3) {
    $ABName2 = $ABSystem2.Name
    Start-Process "C:\users\$env:UserName\downloads\$ABName2"
}
else {
    $ABName3 = $ABSystem3.Name
    Start-Process "C:\users\$env:UserName\downloads\$ABName3"
}}
```

Basically an individual who would use this is going to download one of three versions. Based on what was downloaded, it will match the name and either execute the associated .msi, or expand the zip archive for deployment.

Am I passing in my IF arguments wrong? Can I use "-Match" "-Like", etc. when passing in a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be `if ($ABSystem1.name -match $pattern2)` etc.  And you mispelled "system".

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not think about having to pass .name. Thank you for the typo pointer too. Thought I caught all my "syetem."

Cheers!